# Flattr Gravatar Icons

Tags: flattr

Does anybody know a way how to get access to the Flattr users Gravatar icons in Flattr API v2? Preferred way would be without authentification, since in my project I'm using the API without OAuth2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>The avatar itself is currently not included in any API responses so the only way you can get a gravatar through the API right now is if you request the "extendedread" scope and fetch the e-mail of the authorizing user by fetching https://api.flattr.com/rest/v2/user</del>

<del>Avatars will be added to the responses very soon though, thanks for pointing it out.</del>

As of 31 october there's now an "avatar" key in the user responses which for all users which has chosen to have an avatar will contain the URL to that avatar.

Comment: Great, I'll then wait for the the addition to the API ;)

Comment: Awesome! But could you do me a favor and put it into the `flattrs` stream too? Otherwise I would need to call the `user` API for each user which may result in useless traffic. Like other API's you may also make it optional by specifying fields like: `fields=avatar`. Example: https://api.flattr.com/rest/v2/users/holtwick/flattrs Anyway, thanks a lot for the quick solution!

Comment: I see you added images to the things feed http://developers.flattr.net/api/resources/things/ Still waiting for this to happen to the flattrs feed http://developers.flattr.net/api/resources/flattrs/ Any estimate? Thanks.

Comment: @Holtwick: No plans for that currently - you would like it so that it's easier to make a nice looking list of someones flattrs?

Comment: @VoxPelli: Exactly, this is what it looks like now. Icons would make it more sexy ;) [Screenshot](http://apperdeck.com/tmp/flattr-list.png)

Comment: @Holtwick: A little surprise for you can be found here: http://developers.flattr.net/api/resources/flattrs/ :)

Comment: @VoxPelli: You absolutely made my day! Thanks you very much. If you would like to see the app in action please drop me a note at dirk.holtwick at gmail. Thanks.